# Change UISwitch value without triggering event

Tags: objective-c, ios, controls, uiswitch

I'm trying to change the value of a `UISwitch` based on whether you have enabled location services. I'm setting the target event in the `ViewDidLoad` method, but because you could close the app the load it back up from the background, I'm changing the value of `UISwitch` in the `ViewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.cell2Switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    ...

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(![AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].locationServicesEnabled && self.cell2Switch.on)
    {
        self.cell2Switch.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.cell2Switch setOn:NO];
    }
}
```

When I change the value, it triggers the target event I assigned in the `ViewDidLoad`.

Is there a way I can change the value of the `UISwitch` without it automatically triggering the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to remove the target event.

If the `UISwitch` serves no purpose other than to show you that something is enabled or disabled, then you do no need the target event.